# Method [username] does not exist at login when upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After I recently upgraded Laravel from 5.2 to 5.3, I cannot login in to my app.

For a simple login I receive:
`BadMethodCallException` in `app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php line 82` with the message:

> Method [username] does not exist

I see the cause is from `ThrottlesLogins`. If I remove the Trait called `ThrottlesLogins` from my `AuthController` it will work.

The method `[username]` is from the `ThrottlesLogins` Trait at

```
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip();
}
```

Comment: I have added this method in my `AuthController`:  `public function username() { return 'email';}`. It is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The two default authentication controllers provided with the framework have been split into four smaller controllers. This change provides cleaner, more focused authentication controllers by default. The easiest way to upgrade your application to the new authentication controllers is to grab a fresh copy of each controller from GitHub and place them into your application.

You should also make sure that you are calling the Auth::routes() method in your  routes/web.php file. This method will register the proper routes for the new authentication controllers.

Once these controllers have been placed into your application, you may need to re-implement any customizations you made to these controllers. For example, if you are customizing the authentication guard that is used for authentication, you may need to override the controller's  guard method. You can examine each authentication controller's trait to determine which methods to override.

[Upgrading laravel 5.2 to 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Did you split the Auth controllers and call the new Routes? if not, head over [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3/app/Http/Controllers/Auth) and copy those controllers to your app to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`, then in your `routes/web.php` make sure you're calling `Auth::routes()`, this should be all there is to it.